# bst file how to split sub-strings separated with commas into an item

Tags: bibtex

I wonder how we can split sub-strings separated with comma into a `.bst` file item. For example, I have this in my `.bib` file:

```
Author = {... and ...},
Title  = {...},
Doi    = {doi1, doi2},
```

I have written a function to deal with DOIs:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    {"\href{http://dx.doi.org/" doi * "}{doi:" * doi * "}" *}
  if$
}
```

This works perfectly when there is only one item in the DOI field. But when there are more it no longer works very well. I would like to know how to make a loop inside this function to make it workable for more than one  DOI.
I am not able to find any documentation to learn how to do this. This is an equivalent python of what I would like to do:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    mylist = doi.split(',')
    for element in mylist :
      {"\href{http://dx.doi.org/" element * "}{doi:" * element * "}" *}
      (+ stuffs to deal with comma between the element in the loop)
  if$
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know BibTeX does not have native list handling except for name lists. That means that we will have to build our own parser for comma-separated lists.

I stole the idea for `csv.split.inner` from `biblatex.bst`'s `input:control:parse`. Note that this naive parser assumes that your DOI **lists are separated with a comma *followed by a white space***.

The style uploaded at https://gist.github.com/moewew/6bc573b5f90ba13bb8d2115dfc836e87 shows the function in a modified version of `plainnat.bst`. The general idea can be transplanted to all kinds of `.bst` styles, but the details of `format.doi` and `doi.split.outer` may have to vary from style to style. The diff to the standard `plainnat.bst` is as follows

```
--- plainnat.bst    2010-09-14 11:10:56.000000000 +0200
+++ plainnat-multidoi.bst   2019-02-13 12:36:50.034850700 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,10 @@
+%%%% File: `plainnat-multidoi.bst'
+%%%% A modification of `plainnat.bst' that can deal with multiple DOIs in the
+%%%% doi field.
+%%%% MW, 2019-02-13
+%%%%
+%%%% original copyright header follows
+%%%%
 %% File: `plainnat.bst'
 %% A modification of `plain.bst' for use with natbib package 
 %%
@@ -289,10 +296,49 @@
   if$
 }

+INTEGERS { tempctra tempctrb }
+
+FUNCTION {csv.split.inner} {
+  's :=
+  "" 't :=
+  #1 'tempctra  :=
+  { s empty$ not
+    tempctra and }
+    { s #1 #2 substring$ ", " =
+        { #0 'tempctra := 
+          s #2 global.max$ substring$ 's := }
+        { t s #1 #1 substring$ * 't := }
+      if$
+      s #2 global.max$ substring$ 's :=
+    }
+  while$
+  s
+  t
+}
+
+FUNCTION {doi.split.outer} {
+  's :=
+  ""
+  #0 'tempctrb  :=
+  { s empty$ not }
+    { s csv.split.inner
+      't :=
+      's :=
+      tempctrb #0 =
+        {}
+        { ", " * }
+      if$
+      tempctrb #1 + 'tempctrb  :=
+      "\doi{" t * "}" * *
+    }
+  while$
+}
+
 FUNCTION {format.doi}
 { doi empty$
     { "" }
-    { new.block "\doi{" doi * "}" * }
+    { new.block
+      doi doi.split.outer }
   if$
 }
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{%
  \href{https://doi.org/#1}{doi: \nolinkurl{#1}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor:one,
  Author  = {Anne Uthor},
  Title   = {One DOI},
  Doi     = {10.1000/182},
  year    = {2001},
  journal = {J. Res.},
}
@article{uthor:two,
  Author  = {Anne Uthor},
  Title   = {Two DOIs},
  Doi     = {10.1130/0091-7613(2001), 10.1371/journal.pbio.0020449},
  year    = {2002},
  journal = {J. Res.},
}
@article{uthor:three,
  Author  = {Anne Uthor},
  Title   = {Three DOIs},
  Doi     = {10.1037/a0028240, 10.1090/S0002-9939-00-05422-8, 10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.088302},
  year    = {2003},
  journal = {J. Res.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-multidoi}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Anne Uthor. One doi. J. Res., 2001. doi: 10.1000/182.//Anne Uthor. Two dois. J. Res., 2002. doi: 10.1130/0091-7613(2001), doi: 10.1371/journal.pbio.0020449.//Anne Uthor. Three dois. J. Res., 2003. doi: 10.1037/a0028240, doi: 10.1090/S0002-9939-00-05422-8, doi: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.88.088302.]

Comment: Of course I did it as you solved my issue. Many thanks again for such quick and easy-to-get answer.